# How to logout successfully with spring security using FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm having problems trying to logout from my application, when I press the logout button in my application it shows me the login page again, but if write in the search bar in my browser I can go to any page in my application without having to login again, it seems that when I press the logout link I don't logout at all.

here are my mave dependencies

```
<!-- SPRING SECURITY -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using FreeMarkes as my template engine and I use this expression to have access to Jsp Security Tags.

```
 <#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"] />
```

here is my login controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login/")

public class LoginControl {



@RequestMapping (value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login (Model model, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) 
{

    System.out.println(" logut is " + logout);
    return "/login/login";
}
}
```

And here is my spring security configuration, I'm using a java configuration and no XML

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SeguridadConfiguracion extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



@Autowired 
private AutrProvider aut;



@Override
protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception 
{
    http
        .authenticationProvider(autenticador)
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/sound/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/ajax/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/php/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/xml/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login/login?logout")                                    
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();

}
}
```

and my AutProvider class

```
@Component
public class AutProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {

    String name = null;
    String password = null;
    Authentication auth = null;

    try {
        name = authentication.getName();
        password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (name.equals("admin@admin.com") && password.equals("password")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_DELETE"));

            auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
        }
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

    return auth;
}
```

and here is how I call the logout link in my page

```
<div id="logout" class="btn-header transparent pull-right">
        <span> <a href="../login/login?logout.html" title="Sign Out" data-action="userLogout" data-logout-msg="You can improve your security further after logging out by closing this opened browser"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a> </span>
    </div>
```

I tried changing `href="../login/login?logout.html"` to `href="../j_spring_security_logout`"` but when I do this it says 404 not found.

***EDIT:***

I think that the real problem resides in this lines :

In my spring secuirty configuration class:

```
 .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login/login?logout")                                    
                    .permitAll()
```

This part of My Login Controller:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login (Model model, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) 
{

    System.out.println(" logut is " + logout);
    return "/login/login";
}
```

And this part in page where i call the logout:

```
<a href="../login/login?logout.html"
```

I'm very confused with this link: `j_spring_security_logout` why should I put it in my href if I dont have any controller mapped for that path, is read that that link is some kind of virtual link that is mapped with the path that I put in my spring secuirty configuration class, and I'm not sure but i believed that that link have some kind of functions already defined like closing my session or clearing my crfs tokken (if i later want to use one (since I dont have one in my application right now) ).

***EDIT 2:***

I changed my spring security congifuration class to do this

```
.formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()                                    
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl("/login/logoutPage")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/login")
                .and()
                    .csrf().disable();
```

And i created a new logout page that is the same as the login page (is a copy but with a diferent file name) and I create a new controller method to map this new page. Because when i try to use this controller:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login (Model model, @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) 
{

    System.out.println(" logut is " + logout);
    return "/login/login";
}
```

with this `href="../login/login?logout.html"` it show me the login page again but i'm not logout at all, but when i do it with the new page i create it logs me out fine, but is there a way to use the same page as i'm trying to do.

Also what's the difference between a `logoutUrl()` and `logoutSuccessUrl()`

Answer (score 1):

How about invalidate the current session?
Something like this:

```
  public String logout(HttpSession session) {
    session.invalidate();
    ....
  }
```

Comment: I'm not managing sessions at this point, I don't have any controller with and HttpSession parameter, and all the examples i have looked they don't do that, they use `j_spring_security_logout`, the difference is that i'm using a java class configuration and FreeMarker, i bet that if use JSP and a XML configuration it would work, but i can't change that at this point

Comment: Ok, try to write `<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" title="Sign Out" data-action="userLogout" data-logout-msg="You can improve your security further after logging out by closing this opened browser" >Logout</a>`

Comment: It gives me the same 404 error, i tried with this `href="/j_spring_security_logout"` , I didn't use the the c:url since I'm not using JSP,

Answer (score 0):

> I'm very confused with this link: j_spring_security_logout why should
>   I put it in my href if I dont have any controller mapped for that
>   path, is read that that link is some kind of virtual link that is
>   mapped with the path that I put in my spring secuirty configuration
>   class, and I'm not sure but i believed that that link have some kind
>   of functions already defined like closing my session or clearing my
>   crfs tokken (if i later want to use one (since I dont have one in my
>   application right now) ).

To give you some clarity :

1. Spring security introduces `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter` to each request via security filter chain defined  in your web.xml. Neither Spring framework nor you implement any controller to handle logout.
2. You invoked logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login/login?logout")  on your HttpSecurity object. As per spring security 3.2 documentation

   - For your config, by default, the URL "/logout" will log the user out by invalidating the HTTP Session,*
     so you need to setup your logout URL something like this  in your jsp    :`<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/logout" ../>` . Click to this URL will invalidate the session and redirect (not forward) to the logout success URL (logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html").
3. If you dont even want to use 'logout' keyword and set up 'custom-logout' as the keyword in your URL. Follow something like this.

.logout() .deleteCookies("remove").logoutUrl("/custom-logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success");

Hope this helps your understanding and help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Response to your EDIT 2: As I said, Spring's LogoutFilter intercept each request you send to your application. Now you have specified logout URL as  "/login/logoutPage" . However you submit the URL on click of logout as  /login/login?logout.html.  Spring's Logout Filter will not expire the session as these do not match. Think of Spring' logout filter code as 1. Hey what is the URL being clicked ? Is it same as  "/login/logoutPage" (logout URL) ? If YES ,  expire the session, and redirect to /login/login (logout success URL ).  If NO : Just serve the requested resource.